# searching a line from a text with a keyword (solved) and display the third line after the searched line

Tags: c#

i want to display the third line after searhing the initial line with a keyword from a text :

and i want to sperate all the variable in the third line in textboxs.
the keyword is [Ref 1]

[image: The text file]

```
        {  // string motcledm = "code:A14";
            string line;

            string motcletest = SEARCH.Text;

            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\\TEST.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ((line.Contains(motcletest)))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = line.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

The output i need
[image: THE OUTPUT]

Comment: Do you want ` TextBox1.Text = ''textBox1=F10" `, the line above last image is confusing me

Comment: Kindly read your question its ambiguous.

Comment: i edited the line , when i read it its was kinf of ambiguous , just look at the first picture as an intput , and the second pic as an output

Comment: Right, Now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

As you told, you have extracted the **Third Line**, [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) on ',' to get an array of strings

```
  String thirdLine = "F8,F9,...";
  String[] strArray = thirdLine.Split(',');

  foreach(string _val in strArray){
           //do your stuff
  }
```

Comment: i didnt extract the third line

Comment: You said searching line from keyword solved in question

Comment: yes i search for the the line by a keyword but i cant get the thrid line

Comment: You to get it from the NotePad or file? I thought that was just to format it. Okay I will answer shortly.

Comment: i get it from notpad

Comment: Understood, You want to fetch third line from from a file.txt, split in on `,` and show the output in textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

```
        string line;

        string motcletest = SEARCH.Text;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\\TEST.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((line.Contains(motcletest)))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = line.ToString();
                    file.ReadLine();//read first line after matching line
                    file.ReadLine();//read second line after matching line
                    line = file.ReadLine(); //third line that you are looking for
                    foreach(var value in line.Split(','))//split by ,
                    {
                       //Add the value the controls(textbox)
                       //if the count is not fixed, you might need to create a control and add it to a panel
                    }
                }
            }
```